# redirect to another app with session token (jwt) in AngularJS and NodeJS

Tags: node.js, angularjs

I have a startup module in angularjs. This module is just to login and have public information (login, prices, newsletter...). I have many roles and for each role, i have an app (angular module). I made this architecture because i have complex module for each role and it was impossible to put all roles in one module.

So, for login, i use jsonwebtoken in node like this :

```
var token = jwt.sign(user, config.secureToken, { expiresInMinutes: 20*5});
res.json({ token: token, user: user });
```

It works perfectly. I can login into my app. After that, i have to propose a list of roles to redirect to the right module. 
In angular, I have AuthHttp service that adds security headers (with token) to call rest service with $http.

How can i redirect to 'mydomain:port/anotherModule' with $location or $http ?

With this code in nodejs :

```
app.get('/secondModule', expressJwt({secret: config.secureToken}), function (req, res) {
    res.render('restricted/secondModule/index.html');
});
```

NodeJs sends an html code in response and does'nt redirect...

And if i do this in my angular controller :

```
location.href = route;
```

i have this result on nodejs console :

```
Error: No Authorization header was found
```

Comment: Can you setup the plunker

Comment: i think it's impossible to put nodejs code... i have a simple link to my second module with a function that calls app.get('/secondModule'... in nodejs. Thanks for your reply

Comment: ie, is it possible and how can i use `$location.path(route)` with security token ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure about the libraries you are using, but issue seems that you are loosing the token because you navigate to a altogether new page. 
Based on your auth library you need to pass the token that you get after auth from one page to another.

The options here are to either use browser sessionStorage or querystring to pass the token along and at it back to the http header collection on the new page (module)

Comment: i'm using session token (in session storage). So, i don't loose the token. The problem is I don't send it to server (nodejs) with this instruction : `location.href = route;`. I can't send it because i d'ont use `$http.get(...)`, it's a redirection... and i want to put security on it by sending the session token. thanks.

Comment: Sorry, my last comment was wrong. The problem is i send it with the instruction : `location.href = route;` and not `$http.get(...)`.

Comment: finally i don't use a redirection. It's impossible to send jwt token in location method.

Answer (score 2):

This is an old post but I recently took a long time to figure this out. I may be wrong but I believe nodeJS/expressJS can't read the token from the session storage. I believe you will need to pass the token via the request header using AngularJS.

This depends on the front end that you are using. For me, I am using AngularJS and I have to do something like this.

```
angular.module('AngularApp').factory('authFactory', 
  function($window){    //the window object will be able to access the token

      var auth = {};

      auth.saveToken = function(token){
        $window.localStorage['token_name'] = token;  //saving the token
      }

      auth.getToken = function(){
        return $window.localStorage['token_name'];  //retrieving the token
      }

      return auth;

}

.service('authInterceptor, function(authFactory){
  return { headers: {Authorization: 'Bearer "+ authFactory.getToken()}
}          //the last line gets the retrieved token and put it in req.header
```

Then, you just need to include 'authInterceptor' in all the http methods when you communicate with the backend. This way, nodeJS will be able to pick up the token.

You can see the Authorization field in req.header if you use the chrome developer tool and look at the Network tab. Hope this helps.